# Can't use SASS style in Angular 2 component

Tags: angularjs, angular, npm, sass

According to [this blog](https://github.com/AngularClass/angular2-webpack-starter/wiki/How-to-include-SCSS-in-components), I'm trying to write my component like this.

```
@Component({
  selector: "navbar",
  template: require("./navbar.html"),
  styleUrls: ["./navbar.sass"]
})
```

The error messages I'm getting is 404 on the file *navbar.sass* (it's located in the same directory as the *navbar.ts*) and also this one (that I don't understand and can't tell what to do with).

> Unhandled Promise rejection: Failed to load navbar.sass ; Zone:  ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Failed to load navbar.sass undefined

I have the following loaders defined in my Webpack config file.

```
loaders: [
  { test: /\.png$/, loader: "raw-loader", include: [resources] },
  { test: /\.sass$/, loader: "sass-loader" },
  { test: /\.html$/, loader: "raw-loader", include: [application] },
  { test: /\.ts$/, loader: "ts-loader", include: [application] },
]
```

Those are my loaders from packages list.

> "node-sass": "^4.5.0",
>   "raw-loader": "^0.5.1",
>   "sass-loader": "^5.0.1",
>   "ts-loader": "^2.0.0",...

**edit**

The more elaborated error message is as follows.

> ./source/application/navigation/navbar.sass
>   Module parse failed: C:...\Webular2\node_modules\sass-loader\lib\loader.js!C:...\Webular2\source\application\navigation\navbar.sass Unexpected token (1:4)
>   You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
>   | div {
>   |   background: #dd00ff;
>   |   border: 1px solid #ff9900; }
>    @ ./source/application/navigation/navbar.ts 37:17-41
>    @ ./source/application/app.module.ts
>    @ ./source/application/main.ts
>    @ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3002 ./source/application/main.ts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to embed styles:

```
@Component({
  selector: "navbar",
  template: require("./navbar.html"),
  styles: [require("./navbar.sass")]
})
```

Comment: I got this instead now: `Module parse failed`. However, I can also see in the error message that the SASS file has been transpiled into CSS. Do I need any other loaders or something?

Comment: Please see the edit. I posted it whole. Originally I intended to avoid flooding the text question. My bad.

Comment: In the link that you have provided: `loaders: ['raw-loader', 'sass-loader']` loaders are chained.

Comment: I tested it previously before I even posted the question. I tried **with** `raw-loader` and it didn't work. However, I just realized that at that point I had slashes in front of the `require` for the SASS file. So. Freaking. Stupid. I think it's time to get off the keyboard for a few hours. +1 for persistence. Thanks, mate!